# How to create the include the customized theme for yii2 backend

Tags: php, yii, yii2, themes

First i tell what i actually i did

1) Created the my theme folder yii2\backend\web\themes\basic which contains all my css, js files for theme

2) I configured my theme in yii2\backend\config\main.php as follows:

```
 'components' => [
    'view' => [
        'theme' => [
            'basePath' => '@app/themes/basic',
            'baseUrl' => '@web/themes/basic',
            'pathMap' => [
                '@app/views' => '@app/themes/basic',
            ],
        ]
    ]
],
```

3) Included all my css and js files in the yii2\backend\assets\AppAsset.php

```
     public $basePath = '@webroot';
public $baseUrl = '@web';
public $css = [
    //'css/site.css',
    'plugins/pace/pace-theme-flash.css',
    //'plugins/boostrapv3/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    //'plugins/boostrapv3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css',
    'plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
    'css/animate.min.css',
    'plugins/jquery-scrollbar/jquery.scrollbar.css',
    'css/style.css',
    'css/responsive.css',
    'css/custom-icon-set.css',
];
public $js = [
    //'plugins/jquery-1.8.3.min.js',
    //'plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js',
    //'plugins/boostrapv3/js/bootstrap.min.js',
    'plugins/breakpoints.js',
    'plugins/jquery-unveil/jquery.unveil.min.js',
    'plugins/jquery-scrollbar/jquery.scrollbar.min.js',
    'plugins/jquery-numberAnimate/jquery.animateNumbers.js',
];
public $depends = [
    'yii\web\YiiAsset',
    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
];
```

And my problem is, my css and js was not found it gives the 404 error
My file location is like http://192.168.1.1:1010/backend/web/plugins/pace/pace-theme-flash.css. But my actual file link is http://192.168.1.1:1010/backend/web/themes/basic/plugins/pace/pace-theme-flash.css

Why it is not working. Can anyone help me on this....

Answer (score 0):

If you file location is like you say

```
http://192.168.1.1:1010/backend/web/plugins/pace/pace-theme-flash.css
```

and not

```
http://192.168.1.1:1010/backend/web/themes/basic/plugins/pace/pace-theme-flash.css
```

the your basPath and base Url should be

```
'components' => [
   'view' => [
     'theme' => [
        'basePath' => '@app',
        'baseUrl' => '@web',
        'pathMap' => [
            '@app/views' => '@app/themes/basic',
        ],
    ]
  ]
],
```

and eventually check for app/view  ..

or  in your yii2\backend\assets\AppAsset.php

```
       public $basePath = '@webroot/themes/basic';
       public $baseUrl = '@web/themes/basic';
```

Comment: Thanks scaisEdge for your reply.  It doesn't work. It my css and js files are showing the incorrect path only